Questions about the Stern-Gerlach Experiment Implementation
I have watched this video many times in the hopes of better understanding the SGE and how it is used to conclude that Quantum Spin must be quantized. I have two questions:

During the experiment, 9:40, they heat the cesium atoms in ovens, but they don't appear to shield the ovens? Are the ovens made of a material that deflects magnetic fields? Otherwise, how do they prevent the stray field from the very large magnet in the center of the experiment from coupling back to the source and biasing the cesium atoms? It is said at 19:07 "we know the atoms from the oven have a random distribution of speeds and are also randomly oriented," which would not be true if there was any feedback from the central magnetic field on the atoms in the oven. I ask this question mainly because as the experiment progressed I expected them to talk about how they shielded other parts of the experiment from stray magnetic field, and they simply didn't address it. Yes that field is what they want inside the gap, but it's also filling the room with weird shapes too, and it's not very far from the oven.

At 17:01 we see the results of the first experiment with a weaker magnetic field. It matches exactly what is described as the expected result of a spinning dipole at 21:17. You can literally see them overlaying each other nicely. This appears to be addressed in the video at 20:21 as "the magnetic field was too weak to reveal the splitting." What does that mean exactly? Why would the field be sometimes too weak to reveal the seemingly inherently quantum nature of spin sometimes and other times it is strong enough? If they had only had access to weaker magnets during this experiment, would they have concluded that the spinning bar magnet was the correct model?


In summary, I am trying to understand the right way to think about this experiment that allows you to conclude spin must be quantized, but so far all I'm seeing is what looks to me like odd experimental data? I am trying to understand what I am missing.

"I have watched this video many times... I am trying to understand what I am missing." We can not review and explain every Youtube video on the internet. Have you tried to understand the SGE in some other way besides repeatedly watching Youtube videos?

I am pretty sure the original experiment that is referred to as the Stern-Gerlach experiment uses silver atoms rather than cesium.

@hft were my questions unclear?

@FlatterMann I understand that we cannot recreate it easily. This experiment is one of the core experiments in physics. I am not arguing that the theory has not been tested properly. I am trying to understand what I am NOT understanding. I don't know how to do that in anyway other than explaining what I think should be the case and asking where I have gone wrong. It feels like your response is saying "why are you asking about experiments you can't recreate?" I don't understand at all your point.

@VincentThacker yes, but it should work either way.

@XavierHubbardAnderson Yes.

While I have not watched the video, your questions can be addressed by thinking about the relative strengths of the involved effects:

It is very likely that the heat inside the oven is strong enough that the influence of the magnetic field has a negligible effect compared to the randomization effect of the heat. Even if it did have a significant effect, biasing the atoms along one axis would not cause quantized behavior in itself.
A weak field is not able to accelerate the atoms blasting out of the oven enough to cause the quantized pattern. Technically, any magnetic field would slightly split the beam of atoms in up and down components, but if the splitting is too small it is very hard to detect, and will look almost indistinguishable from a non-splitting result.


Answers to your questions:

In the video, the oven is about a meter from the magnet. They point the axis of their coils away from the oven, so there won't be a strong magnetic field at the oven.
I think you missed the point that, in the classical way of thinking, all field gradients would give a single bump. In the experiment, the low-field gradient is essentially no field because of the angular spread of the beam: you can't resolve two bumps because they are washed out by the spread.

I think I can help nudge you toward seeing that two bumps suggest quantization.
In the video, they didn't mention the case of a classical dipole perfectly perpendicular to the field gradient. They only told you about the parallel and anti-parallel cases (around 7:07). A classical perpendicular dipole will not be deflected. This should make sense because it's the halfway condition between parallel and antiparallel$^\dagger$.
The oven emits all orientations, so, in the classical view, you should see intensity at the center of the plot even in the high-field gradient case because the perpendicular orientations should go straight through undeflected. But you don't see anything there. So, the classical reasoning about perpendicular orientations is incorrect.
Now, switch to quantum mechanics. Let's say the magnetic field axis is along the $z$-direction. One perpendicular-oriented magnetic dipole could be along the $y$-direction. I suggest you consider that, in quantum mechanics, this state could be represented as $$|+y\rangle=c_1|+z\rangle + c_2|-z\rangle.$$ The magnetic field (which is in the $z$-direction) will act on the dipoles of the kets with $z$ in them. Moreover, all orientations can be written as superpositions of the $z$ kets with different values of $c_1$ and $c_2$, which means all atoms of all orientations will split like they are parallel and antiparallel dipoles along the $z$-direction.
$^\dagger$If you know about vectors and dot products, you can understand how strongly different classical orientations feel a force if I mention that at 6:55 the equation is more appropriately written with a dot product: $$ \vec{F}=\vec{\mu}\cdot\partial_x B.$$
